# Git clone using https on mainframe zdnt slave node

Tags: git, mainframe

When I am doing the https git clone on mainframe zdnt slave node in Jenkins - I am getting error as follows

```
 > /hfs/rocket/bin/git fetch --tags --progress -- https://XXX/Rahul_Udaykumar/ibm-dbb-mort.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/hfs/rocket/bin/git fetch --tags --progress -- https://XXX/Rahul_Udaykumar/ibm-dbb-mort.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
 
stderr:
```

Comment: does your ssh git clone works fine?

Answer (score 0):

The Rocket zOpen Source Zone [Git for zOS 2.26.2 - Release Notes.pdf](https://my.rocketsoftware.com/RocketCommunity#:%7E:text=Git%20for%20zOS%202.26.2%20-%20Release%20Notes.pdf) it outlines several restrictions.  The download is free but you have to register.  I've included the restrictions below.  One of them is that Git on z/OS can only operate in client mode.

```
Restrictions
Some files used by Git must be encoded as ISO8859-1 or UTF-8. These include:
Git attribute files, whether in .git/info/attributes or .gitattributes
.gitignore files

The only remote protocols supported are ssh and https.

Only client mode is supported; in other words, Git for z/OS can clone from,
and push to, remote repositories via ssh or https, but
cannot be the target of clone and push from other clients.

In heterogeneous deployments (e.g. both USS and Windows Git clients), the 
limitations of your zos-working-tree-encoding attribute
choices must be respected across all Git clients. For example, given two Git 
client clones of a text file - one on USS using IBM-1047
encoding and one on Windows using UTF-8 encoding - you must not add an IBM-930 
character to the same file on your Windows system.
The Git interface to Subversion (git-svn) is not supported.
```